# How to add tags programmatically using JQuery to WordPress Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Trying to add tags programmatically using JQuery but can not achieve the task

[image: add tags]

Comment: Please explain why you need this functionality.

Comment: Our plugin has a metabox that offers suggestions for tags based on a specific keyword. the user then selects some of the suggested tags to use as WordPress tags

Comment: did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Unfortunately, No. I think when we write the tag, an ajax request get issued on the background to add this tag and return an ID for it so it is more than just inserting a text to the box